# customlistadapter TextView values get change when scrolled down and set to its initial value

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

In CustomListAdapter I have a increment button and a textview to show its value,when I click on increment button I increment the value then store it to the sqlite db then I fetch that value and then I set it to the respective textview.

But when I scroll down then its value get change to its intial value i.e "0"
I referred to a similar question before, they suggested to use viewholder I used that also but didnot helped me.
I would appreciate anyone guiding me on how to do this.
Here is CustomListAdapter code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
  private SQLiteHandler db;
//    HashMap<Integer,Integer> quantity = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<com.example.malli.myapplication.model.Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();

public CustomListAdapter2(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
    Log.d("size",String.valueOf(movieItems.size()));

    db = new SQLiteHandler(activity.getApplicationContext());
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)       


   {
     ViewHolderItem viewHolder = null;
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row2, null);


            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
          viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);          
          viewHolder.rating=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
          viewHolder.genre=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
      viewHolder.addbutton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        viewHolder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

        }
            final Integer uniqueKey = Integer.valueOf(position);
            final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

            // store the holder with the view.
            //    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            for(int j =0;j<20;j++){

                 String val1=db.getUser(j);

              if(val1 != null) {
                   viewHolder.qty.setText(db.getUser(j));
              }
               else{
                    viewHolder.qty.setText("0");
                   }
            }

    final ViewHolderItem finalViewHolder = viewHolder;

    viewHolder.addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String val = finalViewHolder.qty.getText().toString();
            if(val == null)
            val= String.valueOf(1);
            else {
                val = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(val) + 1);
            Log.d("val",String.valueOf(val));
            } 
            db.add(m.getTitle(), String.valueOf(val),    
    String.valueOf(m.getRating1(),String.valueOf(m.getRating1()));

             String val2 = db.getUser(m.getRating1());
            finalViewHolder.qty.setText(db.getUser(m.getRating1()));
                db.addtotalcost(String.valueOf(
            Integer.valueOf(val)*m.getRating1()));
            String totalcost = db.getTotalCost2();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new  
                ChargingEvent(Integer.valueOf(totalcost)));

                }
    });
    // thumbnail image
    viewHolder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    viewHolder.title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    viewHolder.rating.setText("Cost: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating1()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    viewHolder.genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    //year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
   }
  }
```

Comment: not so sure where exactly that affects, but you are getting a Movie from `movieItems`, then do some work on it and do some work on db, at this stage the list `movieItems` still holds old data for the item @position, what you need to **1** either refresh this list (reload from where ever you get it) **2** update the values in `m` and add it to `movieItems` in same position `movieItems.set(position, m);` [do this after setting new values in `m`]

Comment: @yazan i didnot get it

Comment: the value you are talking about, is it in a Movie object? if yes, which one?

Comment: @yazan the value is not in the movie object

Comment: if it's stored/fetched always from db, then you need to make sure db code that update the value is correct, maybe it's not updated in db, and thats why you keep getting initial value (0)

Comment: @yazan I checked the db by printing their vales in Log and they are correct

Comment: @yazan as u have said i used the setter  and getter method to set the values and added these lines  String val1 = db.getQty(m.getRating1());
                Log.d("val1",db.getQty(m.getRating1()));
                m.setqty(val1);
                Log.d("getqty",m.getqty());
                finalViewHolder.qty.setText(m.getqty()); but it didnot worked for me

Comment: add this line `movieItems.set(position, m);` after `m.setqty(val1);`, if this did not work, then i am not sure what is the problem

Comment: @yazan forget to reply...........thnks that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line

`movieItems.set(position, m);`

after

`m.setqty(val1);`

this will update the value of the property in the data set, so the adapter view the new data when it's rendered by `getView()`